# How does scoring work in Word Derby?

Tags: word-derby

The scores in Word Derby mostly make scrabble-sense, but occasionally I score 20-30 points more than I expected and I haven't been able to figure out why.

Understanding this mechanic would obviously be very helpful.

[The Modojo Review](http://www.modojo.com/reviews/word_derby) mentions "triple-word scores, double-letter scores and so on" but fails to explain how to get them.

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways on how you can receive bonus points in Word Derby, through timer, multiplier and bonus tiles.

- You start from the base letter score in the top right corner of each tile
- You get up to 5 bonus points for speed
- You get bonus points from double and triple word and letter spaces. If you can, make sure that the letter that falls on that area has a high point value to maximize your score.

For the full details, you can read this article about [Word Derby](http://scrabblewordfinders.net/whats-word-derby/).